# Bokeh layout update on CustomJS callback

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs, pandas-bokeh

I am new to `bokehJS` and I need to update the plot based on `dropdown` values.
For initial load am using below code to add `arrow` in layout of the plot. But, whenever I change the value on `dropdown` plot gets updated however `arrow` gets disappear.

```
p.add_layout(Arrow(end=TeeHead(line_width=0), x_start=0, y_start=min(source1.data['y']),
                           x_end=0, y_end=max(source1.data['y']), line_dash="dashed"))
```

Below is the custom js `callback` I written:

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source1=test_vs_control_source1, source2=test_vs_control_source2, 
                              data=data, leg=p.legend.items, tt=p.hover), code=
    switch(cb_obj.value) {
      case 'Actuals':
        // code block
        source1.data = data.actual.testgroup;
        source2.data = data.actual.controlgroup;
        leg[0].label.value = 'Test Group';
        leg[1].label.value = 'Control Group'
        tt[0].tooltips = "<div>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">T_Post: $x{0,0}</span><br/>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:orange;">C_Post: $y{0,0}</span>
          </div>";
        break;
      case 'Impact':
        // code block
        source1.data = data.impact;
        source2.data = {'x':[],'y':[]};
        leg[0].label.value = 'Impact';
        leg[1].label.value = '';
        tt[0].tooltips = "<div>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">Impact: $x{0,0}</span>
          </div>";
        break;
      case 'Lift':
        // code block
        source1.data = data.lift;
        source2.data = {'x':[],'y':[]};
        leg[0].label.value = 'Lift';
        leg[1].label.value = '';
        tt[0].tooltips = "<div>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">Lift: $x{0,0}</span>
          </div>";
        break;
      default:
        // code block
        leg[0].label.value = 'Test Group';
        leg[1].label.value = 'Control Group';
        tt[0].tooltips = "<div>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">T1_Post: $x{0,0}</span><br/>
             <span style="font-size: 18px;color:orange;">C_Post: $y{0,0}</span>
          </div>";
        source1.data = data.testvscontrol.testgroup;
        source2.data = data.testvscontrol.controlgroup;
    }
    
    source1.change.emit();
    source2.change.emit();
```

)

How can I edit layout in `callbackJS`?

Note: I want this as standalone html page so not willing to use bokeh server.

Comment: Please edit your post to use proper code block formatting, it's not currently intelligible.

Comment: @bigreddot editing is done. could you please have look at it?

Comment: better show minimal working code which we could run and test ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out an answer for my question after couple of trial and errors:
Below is my updated callback customJS

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source1=test_vs_control_source1, source2=test_vs_control_source2, 
                          data=data, legend=plot.legend.items, tooltip=plot.hover, arr=arrow, plot=plot, thead=thead,
                          yaxis=plot.yaxis, formatter=formatter, label=label), code="""
switch(cb_obj.value) {
  case 'Actuals':
    // code block
    source1.data = data.actual.testgroup;
    source2.data = data.actual.controlgroup;
    legend[0].label.value = 'Test Group';
    legend[1].label.value = 'Control Group'
    tooltip[0].tooltips = "<div>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">T_Post: $x{0,0}</span><br/>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:orange;">C_Post: $y{0,0}</span>
      </div>";  
    formatter.format = '0';
    break;
  case 'Impact':
    // code block
    source1.data = data.impact;
    source2.data = {'x':[],'y':[]};
    legend[0].label.value = 'Impact';
    legend[1].label.value = '';
    tooltip[0].tooltips = "<div>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">Impact: $x{0,0}</span>
      </div>";    
    formatter.format = '0.000000';
    break;
  case 'Lift':
    // code block
    source1.data = data.lift;
    source2.data = {'x':[],'y':[]};
    legend[0].label.value = 'Lift';
    legend[1].label.value = '';
    tooltip[0].tooltips = "<div>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">Lift: $x{0,0}</span>
      </div>";
    formatter.format = '0.0000';
    break;
  default:
    // code block
    legend[0].label.value = 'Test Group';
    legend[1].label.value = 'Control Group';
    tooltip[0].tooltips = "<div>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:deepskyblue;">T_Post: $x{0,0}</span><br/>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;color:orange;">C_Post: $y{0,0}</span>
      </div>";
    formatter.format = '0';
    source1.data = data.testvscontrol.testgroup;
    source2.data = data.testvscontrol.controlgroup;        
}

 arr.x_start = 0;
 arr.x_end = 0;
 arr.y_start = Math.min.apply(null, source1.data['y']);
 arr.y_end = Math.max.apply(null, source1.data['y']);
 arr.line_dash = 'dashed';
 arr.end = thead;
 plot.add_layout(arr);
 
 label.text = 'Event';
 label.render_mode = 'css';
 label.border_line_alpha = 1.0;
 label.background_fill_color = 'white';
 label.background_fill_alpha = 1.0;
 label.angle = 300;
 label.x = 0;
 label.y = Math.max.apply(null, source1.data['y']);
 plot.add_layout(label);
 
 yaxis[0].formatter = formatter;     
 source1.change.emit();
 source2.change.emit();
```

""")